# Does BigQuery supports loading HDFS style partitioned data?

Tags: hadoop, google-bigquery

In HDFS, partitioned data is stored as multiple files like

```
hdfs://user/hive/warehouse/TABLE_NAME/column_1="VALUE"/column_2="VALUE"/000000
```

Does big query supports loading these files as they are or is it necessary to flatten the data into one single file?
Nothing is mentioned in the documentation regarding loading the files as they are.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple files can be loaded in bigquery comes under same directory, So no need to flatten.
Below is the sample code:

```
bq load --replace --quote "" -F"\t"  ${db_name}.${tgt_table_name}\$${bq_partition} gs://bucket_name/folder/*
```

Let me know if it helps or not.